# 2nd floor zone is blowing cold air out the return. Nothing from the usual vents

Tags: air-conditioning

I could not turn it off just by setting that zone to off.  The fan appears to be running in reverse.  The only way I was able to stop it was to set the master zone downstairs to off.

I am in my eighties and having the AC off tonight is not good.  It is a good thing it cooled off somewhat tonight.

Do some systems contain a baffle that might be stuck in the wrong position?

Comment: We need more details, model numbers, diagrams or photos

Comment: If air is blowing out of the _return_ ... I haven't dealt with a forced air system, but that seems backward. Or does airflow reverse between heating and cooling modes?

Answer (score 1):

The only logically for that to happen is as you said for the blower to run backwards. This can happen with some motors if the start switch fails and it gets a nudge in either direction it will run in that direction. It is the relationship between the start winding and the run winding that controls the direction.

I would recommend if you are not up to it getting a professional in to check this out. This could also be your yearly furnace inspection in the same visit. If I am correct it is only a matter of time till the motor fry by overheating. You did the correct thing and shut it down but I would not start it until the cause of the problem has been found.

Comment: If the capacitor for the blower motor has died, that could set the stage for an induction motor to get itself started going the wrong direction..